# Use obj/this in "on" method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

My javascript looks like

```
$('.adv_group').each(function(){
    var eachAdvGroup = $(this);
    $(document).on('keypress', **eachAdvGroup.find('.userinput:last')** ,function(){
         //do something
    }
})
```

I knew that 'on' only takes String, so how to translate **$(this).find('.userinput:last')** into a string?

P.S. I want to get last **.userinput** in every **.adv_group**

Comment: You could try `$(document).on('keypress', '.userinput:last', function() {});`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just do do:

```
$('.adv_group').on('keypress', '.userinput:last', function(){
    ........
});
```

Jquery internally does a loop through on all matching `.adv_group`.

And if you mean that `.adv_group` is not guaranteed to exist all the time then either delegate it to another parent or to the document.

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.adv_group .userinput:last-of-type', function(){
    ........
});
```

Since adv_group is generated on the fly inorder to have it selected at every level you need to use `:last-of-type` or `:last-child` and not `:last`, so that it selects last `.userInput` of every `.adv_group` instead of last of all `.userInput` of all adv_groups combined.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KWbQk/show)**

Comment: @nietonfir if you are binding it to document head you dont need to use it in document ready, otherwise yes. But i always suggest to stick as much close to the available parent as possible than just delegating everything to the document head.

Comment: I actually want to get last userinput in every adv_group

Comment: First one is not working since I generate .adv_group on the go. Second one only working with the userinput:last not the userinput:last in every adv_group.

Comment: @McDream is adv_group is written on the fly?

Comment: If you type in more than one word, it will alert more than once. Is it possible to only alert once when I type in that field?

Comment: @McDream You mentioned keypress in your qn as well. That is what keypress means it will trigger for every keypress. What do you WANT?

Comment: This is working on jsfiddle but I don't know why mine not working. I will figure it out :) Thanks! @PSL http://jsfiddle.net/JHyQF/1/

Answer (score 1):

The `$.each()` call is totally unnecessary, all you need is

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.adv_group .userinput:last-of-type', function(e) {
     var $ele = $(this);
     //do something
}
```

Comment: fyi.. `:last` will not work in this case, see mu answer updated. You can fix it in yours as well

Comment: @PSL Indeed. `:last-child` should do the job as well imho.